Help with power calculation
I want to to an experiment, where in each trial you have one of out 3 possible reports, associated each with a unique effect size. I am currently considering simulating $N$ amount of trials from a multinomial distribution, where each state is associated with a unique probability
probs <- c(0.1, 0.4, 0.5)
num_samples <- 40
samples <- rmultinom(num_samples, n, probs)

and then, based on the sample, I will add the appropriate effect size.
Is there a way to add random effects to such a model, such that the probabilities will for each state will vary per person? If so, how would you ensure they sum to 1? Also, how would you account for the fact that variation of the lowest probability (.1) will result very frequently in not sampling from that state? I cannot go above 40 trials.

"such that the probabilities will for each state will vary per person? If so, how would you ensure they sum to 1?" ... see the Dirichlet distribution. One simple  possibility if you don't have a function to generate from the Dirichlet is to take Gamma random variables with the same scale (unit scale will do) and use their proportion of their sum.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Random_variate_generation . It's not the only way to do what you're trying to do, but it's a common and fairly convenient way.
